# How to .bashrc for root in Docker

Tags: docker, bash

I want to give my root user in a (`centos:6`) Docker container a `.bashrc`. However, when I run my container, I find that the `.bashrc` has not been sourced. Can this be done?

My build command:

```
...
RUN touch .bashrc
RUN echo "iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d hostA -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to hostB" >> .bashrc
...
```

My run command:

```
docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN myImage /bin/bash
```

Comment: try to put your 2 commands in a `CMD` separated by a `;` and rebuild /relaunch

Comment: So, if I do that and run it without the `/bin/bash` part of the run command, it runs but doesn't give me interactive control of the container.

Comment: I mean, when your new image is built, then `docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN mynewimage /bin/bash`

Comment: @user2915097 that causes the CMD to not be executed since it's being replaced.

Comment: replace CMD by ENTRYPOINT and rebuild

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Turns out I was adding the file incorrectly. It should be `/root/.bashrc` rather than just `.bashrc`. With the file added in the correct place, no run command or CMD is required.

Build

```
...
ADD iptables /iptables
RUN touch /root/.bashrc \
 && cat iptables >> /root/.bashrc
...
```

Run

```
docker run -it --cap-add=NET_ADMIN myImage /bin/bash
```

Comment: You don't need to `touch`, since the `>>` will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9):

The [bash manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) states that `.bashrc` is read when the shell is interactive. Thus, if you want a bash that reads `.bashrc`, you need to launch bash with `-i`.

See that:

```
root@host:~# echo 'echo this is .bashrc' > /tmp/bashrc
root@host:~# docker run -ti -v /tmp/bashrc:/root/.bashrc debian bash -i 
this is .bashrc
root@01da3a7e9594:/#
```

But, executing `bash -i` like this in the container, overrides the entrypoint or cmd, so you might be better with wrapping the iptables command and the entrypoint you are originally using in a shell script that becomes your entrypoint / cmd.

Comment: I found this answer would be the right answer to this question. When we launch the container without setting ENV. It would not source the bashrc no matter root or not. Set the `BASH_ENV` could be the right way to figure it out.