# Problems in activating conda enviroment in docker

Tags: python, bash, docker, conda

I would like to set permanently a conda environment in my docker image in order that the functions of the conda package could be used by the script given as argument to the entrypoint. 
This is the dockerfile that I created.

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

RUN conda create -n myenv
RUN echo "source activate myenv" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH:="/opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin:$PATH"
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

It seems that the `~/.bashrc` file is not sourced when I run the docker container. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284667/how-to-bashrc-for-root-in-docker

Answer (score 1):

As a work around either use 'SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-i", "--login", "-c"]'

-or-

edit the .bashrc file in the image to not exit if not in interactive mode by changing "*) return;;" to read "*) ;;"

Using the first option bash will complain about job control and ttys, but the error can be ignored.

cause of the issue:

the .bashrc file contains the following command:

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

which causes bash to stop sourcing the file if not in interactive mode. (the -i flag)

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way for the conda stanza to be inserted into .bash_profile or .profile automatically instead of (or in addition to) .bashrc, as there doesn't seem to be an option to override or add to the list of what files conda init examines for modification.

Comment: An example Dockerfile fragment:

```
ENV VENV="./my-virtual-env"
RUN conda create -y --prefix "$VENV" python=3.7.*
RUN conda init bash
RUN sed -i 's/ return;;/;;/g' .bashrc
RUN echo "conda activate $VENV" >> .bashrc

RUN echo "$PATH"
RUN which python
RUN which pip
```